# Call static method to get absolute URL of SharePoint 2010 document

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm attempting to retrieve the URL of the current document in a SharePoint 2010 document library so it can be added to an email in a SharePoint 2010 workflow.

Currently, I have the following code in a Utilities.cs file:

```
namespace WorkflowProject1.Workflow1
{
    public static class Utilities
    {
        public static string AbsoluteUrl(this SPFile File)
        {
            string EncodedUrl = File.Item[SPBuiltInFieldId.EncodedAbsUrl].ToString();
            string DecodedURL = SPEncode.UrlDecodeAsUrl(EncodedUrl);
            return DecodedURL;            

        }        

    }
}
```

In my workflow file (Workflow1.cs) with the same namespace I am trying to call the above method using the following line:

`Item.File.AbsoluteUrl();`

When I attempt to call the method I get "the name Item does not exist in the current context". Am I missing a reference? Any suggestions on how to retrieve  the DecodedURL value so I can use it in my main workflow file would be greatly appreciated. Also, most of this code was copied from another post but I do not have enough points to comment on the original post.

Comment: There is no way for people on SO to know what type of object `Item` is, especially even if your compiler can't figure it out... More context could help. Also there is no points requirement to link to questions you took source from.

Comment: Hello Alexei,  Thanks for the feedback. The original post can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216832/how-to-get-the-absolute-url-of-a-file-in-sharepoint-library .  I'm referring to the second answer to the question in the above link. I will post additional code later today

Answer (score 0):

Since (based on this method) you already have retrieved the correct SPFile object you should be able to refer to the url property.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.url(v=office.14).aspx

If you would like the absolute URL you can use the field `EncodedAbsUrl` on the SPFile (this also works with SPListItems):

Usage (assuming your `SPFile` object is called `file`):

```
string absoluteUrl = (string) file.Item[SPBuiltInFieldId.EncodedAbsUrl];
```

Documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/LIBRary/microsoft.sharepoint.spbuiltinfieldid.encodedabsurl.aspx

Comment: Hello ElvisLikeBear, thanks for the link but I believe the above approach gets the site-relative URL of the file and I was hoping to get the decoded absolute URL of the file by accessing the return variable DecodedURL . Any suggestions?

Comment: @user3400457 Sorry, you're correct. Updated my answer to reflect this!

Comment: Thanks for the update but I need to invoke: public static string AbsoluteUrl(this SPFile File) in the workflow in order to retrieve the DecodedURL value. For instance something along the lines of:         private void CodeActivity(SPFile File)
        {
          absoluteUrl = Utilities.AbsoluteUrl(File);

        }