# Can i copy a .OFT file and change its Subject

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code inside my sharepoint event reciever to copy a .oft file inside a document library and paste it inside a new destination (another document library):-

```
SPDocumentLibrary template = (SPDocumentLibrary)properties.Web.GetList(properties.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/Templates/");
SPListItem templetefile = null;

foreach (SPListItem i in template.Items)
{
    if (i.Name.ToLower().Contains("project"))
    {
         templetefile = i;    
    }
}

byte[] fileBytes = templetefile.File.OpenBinary();
string destUrl = properties.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + projectid.RootFolder.Url +".oft";
SPFile destFile = projectid.RootFolder.Files.Add(destUrl, fileBytes, false);
```

now my code is working well. but i am not sure if i can access the .OFT file after its being copied, and modify its subject (by subject i mean i email subject) ??

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40038804/modifying-outlook-oft-files-via-c-sharp

Comment: Why aren't you sure if you can? Did you try it? What was the result?

Comment: It looks like this is already solved, or do you still have problems?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Interop for that.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();    
MailItem mail = application.CreateItemFromTemplate("oldfile.oft") as MailItem;

mail.BodyFormat = OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
mail.Subject = "New Subject";
mail.HTMLBody = "<p>This is a new <strong>OFT</strong> file with a changed subject line.</p>";
mail.SaveAs("newfile.oft");
```

For other users who cannot find Interop in Visual Studio, add a Reference.

`References` > `Add Reference` > `COM` > `Microsoft Outlook 15.0 Object Library`

**Update**

Since I do not have SharePoint (or ever worked with it), I cannot test this. But maybe something like this can work? Use the `Url` of the `SPListItem` to get the correct file. You could also try the absolute url as seen in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216832/how-to-get-the-absolute-url-of-a-file-in-sharepoint-library). Use that string to load the file for editing.

```
foreach (SPListItem i in template.Items)
{
    if (i.Name.ToLower().Contains("project"))
    {
        string url = i.Url;
        string absoluteUrl = (string)i[SPBuiltInFieldId.EncodedAbsUrl];

        MailItem mail = application.CreateItemFromTemplate(url) as MailItem;

        //or

        MailItem mail = application.CreateItemFromTemplate(absoluteUrl) as MailItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. but inside this line of code `application.CreateItemFromTemplate("oldfile.oft") as MailItem` how i can reference the file which is already stored inside a document library, i am getting this file inside my `foreach` loop.. and seocnd question how i template file already have a Body , and i do not want to modify it .. but i  only want to modify the subject is this possible ?

Comment: I've updated my answer with something you can try. This is not tested since I do not have SharePoint. And changing the body is optional, you can remove that from my first snippet part if you do not make changes to it.

Comment: now inside my visual studio 2012 i can not find a reference named "Microsoft Outlook 15.0 Object Library".. so is this something i can install inside my VS project? and i am planning to deploy my code inside IIS.. so will i need to install outlook on that server (the sharepoint server)??

Comment: Yes you need Office with Outlook installed on the server as well. That is why I usually do not recommend Interop.

Comment: so what is the other appraoch to do so? i mean if i need to modify the `.oft` subject ,, then what are the other lighter approaches which i can follow, that does not require having office with Outlook installed!!!

Comment: I haven't found any other options. I also looked for a 3rd party library but could not find one. The only alternative I can think of is to do a search and replace in the byte array of the file itself: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3226/replace-sequence-of-strings-in-binary-file or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132890/c-sharp-replace-bytes-in-byte

Comment: @johnG - I think that if you use dynamic you could at least save the need to install it on your workstation, as you won't get any compiler errors. e.g. `var outlookType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Outlook.Application",true); dynamic outlook = Activator.CreateInstance(outlookType)` then use the rest of the API mentioned in VDWWD answer (you won't have intellisense though).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the need to install/use outlook, you can check out [Aspose.Email](https://products.aspose.com/email/net).

> Aspose.Email for .NET is a complete set of Email Processing APIs to be
>   used with .NET Framework, .NET Core & Xamarin platforms, enabling you
>   to build cross-platform applications having the ability to create,
>   manipulate, convert and transmit emails **without using Microsoft
>   Outlook**

It supports OFT files as well